# Why does version two of this simple calculator work as it should while version one does not? Is it because of the order of the operators in the code?

Tags: python, pycharm, calculator

Here is version 1 of my simple calculator.

```
num1 = float(input("Enter first number: "))
op = input("Enter operator: ")
num2 = float(input("Enter second number: "))

if op == "+":
    print(num1 + num2)
elif op == "-":
    print(num1 - num2)
elif op == "*" or "x":
    print(num1 * num2)
elif op == "/" or "divide":
    print(num1 / num2)
else:
    print("You have not entered a valid number or operator")
```

Now, here is version two of my simple calculator.

```
num1 = float(input("Enter first number: "))
op = input("Enter operator: ")
num2 = float(input("Enter second number: "))

if op == "+":
    print(num1 + num2)
elif op == "-":
    print(num1 - num2)
elif op == "/":
    print(num1 / num2)
elif op == "*" or "x":
    print(num1 * num2)
else:
    print("Invalid operator")
```

Could someone tell me why all of the operators in version two while one of the operators in version one doesn't work in the PyCharm IDE?

Comment: or "x" will always be true

Comment: Look at how [Boolean Comparison](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) works